# Where is node_modules global location

Tags: nodejs

Where is node_modules installed globally on Ubuntu 20.04 ?
It's not there in /usr/local/lib
I want to get rid of globally installed webpack. I can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

The two other common locations for modules that I've seen are:

```
/opt/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/include/node_modules
```

Hopefully one of those two contain the web pack you're looking to remove. If not, search the file system:

```
sudo find / -iname "node_modules" -type d
```

This will list all directories named `node_modules`. Using `-iname` makes the search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

In a Dockerfile I install like this

RUN apt-get update -y 
&& apt-get upgrade -y 
&& apt-get install -y 
&& curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - 
&& apt-get install -y nodejs

... it places them in

/usr/lib/node_modules

/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules